# How to debug package-install failing to install package

Tags: macos, emacs, elpa

I'm trying to install `auctex` which is on the the gnu `elpa.gnu.org` repo but it gets stuck for some reason on downloading.

I can't find anything online for this problem so I'm guessing this is something specific to my setup and not something wrong with ELPA. I'm using a port of Emacs for OS X which isn't Aquamacs and isn't vanilla emacs. I use the `Emacs.app` that comes with it to launch the GUI version. I've already started trying to disable parts of my init.el but it's a lot pieces of code and I want to help narrow things down first.

Here is what I have in `*messages*`

```
Making completion list... [2 times]
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Opening TLS connection to `elpa.gnu.org'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 elpa.gnu.org'...done
Opening TLS connection to `elpa.gnu.org'...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Buffer " *epg*" has a running process; kill it? (y or n) y
Quit
```

How do I debug this situation? I am guessing I need to debug the part where it tries to contact `elpa.gnu.org` since thats where I eventually need to kill it, but I'm not even sure how to start my version of Emacs in debug mode.

This is my version of emacs: https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac

Installed using this homebrew recipe: https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port

I'm trying to avoid downloading and installing `auctex` manually if possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a little workaround: if you want to avoid installing AUCTeX manually, you can go to [the auctex page](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html) in the [package list](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/) of GNU ELPA, download the `auctex-11.89.3.tar` from that page through the web browser, and then in Emacs type `M-x package-install-file` to install that tar file.  The end result is the same as if Emacs had downloaded and installed the package for you: AUCTeX will be managed by the Emacs package manager.

It seems like something is going wrong when Emacs tries to download the file, so this can be a way to circumvent the problem.  If you want to figure out what's happening, I'd suggest downloading [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and capturing the network traffic while Emacs is trying to download the file. (You might find [this intro video](https://www.wireshark.org/video/wireshark/introduction-to-wireshark/) helpful.) My guess is that you'll see some TLS alerts or TCP connection resets, which could be a pointer to where to start looking for the error.